# p5.js - When to declare variables using var vs this.varName

Tags: processing, var, p5.js

I'm still figuring out how to use p5.js. In regular java you have to declare each variable using its data type, ex. `int foo = 0`.

In p5, I know you can just use `var foo` but you can also declare variables using `this.foo`. If someone could clarify when is the proper time to use `var` and when i can use `this`, that would be very helpful.

For example, if I want to declare a variable inside a method,  should i use `var foo = thing` or could I declare it using `this.foo = thing`? What should I use when declaring global variables or when referring to objects passed into methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, p5 is not a language, it is a Javascript library, you are coding in Javascript, not p5.

Coming to your question, if you want to use some function as a data type, similar to a class in java, and want all the "instances" of that to have their own different variables, you use `this`. If they are just variables you use in someway but don't need to be specific for each instance, or if the function is not a constructor function and is not to be used as a data type, you will just use `var` then.

Again, there is no class stuff in javascript, you will have to write what is called a constructor function in order to "simulate" a java class, but be aware that a constructor function should not return anything. Here is an example of `car` class in java:

```
class car {
  int speed = ___;
  String model = ___;
  static int numOfWheels = ___;
}
```

This is what it will look like in javascript (a constructor function):

```
function car() {
  this.speed = ____;
  this.model = ____;
  var numOfWheels = ___;
}
```

If you declare a variable without `this`, it can be roughly compared to a static variable in a java class in the sense that it will be constant among all the instances.

So basically, at least in most cases, you will use `this.varName` usually inside constructor functions, i.e., functions that you will use to construct objects.

> What should I use when declaring global variables or when referring to objects passed into methods?

Global variables will almost always be `var something = something`. When referring to objects passed into functions, just use the dot notation to refer to its properties like `passedObject.someProperty`

I would recommend you to learn Javascript before jumping into p5 directly, here are some resources that I found useful when I started learning Javascript-

- [w3 School](https://www.w3schools.com/js)
- [JavaScript Info Website](https://javascript.info/)
- [TheNewBoston](https://thenewboston.com/videos.php?cat=10)